# console.log backbone model, attributes property

Tags: javascript, firebug

I wanted to make sure I understood Firebug correctly.  I print out my model.  And in the console of firebug, I see in the attributes, it has "myProperty".  But then when I do this:

```
if (_.has(model, "myProperty"))
```

or

```
if (model.hasOwnProperty('myProperty'))
```

Both do not return a result. Is there somethign I'm not understanding about Firebug or JS?  Thanks.

Comment: considering that we are talking about JS, does "hasOwnProeprty" exact spelling or was just a typo ?

Comment: If neither give true, test `'myProperty' in model`. If this is true then the property is inherited from the prototype chain (as `hasOwnProperty` was `false`). If this is `false` but you can still access some `model.myProperty`, then perhaps it is a binding rather than a key.

Comment: @PaulS. Ok I tried `if ("myProperty" in model) and that also returned nothing.  Any other thoughts?  I also cannot access `model.myProperty`

Comment: Sounds like _myProperty_ is **not a property** (own or inherited, enumerable or nonenumerable) of `model` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `myProperty` is an attribute you've given the model, then it will exist in the attributes object: `model.attributes.myProperty`. Does it?

Note that in [the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-has), if `myProperty` is null or undefined then `model.has(myProperty)` will return `false`.

Comment: I guess what confused me is why you have to model.attributes.  I'd think it'd just work with model.something.  But I am JS noob so what do I know.

Comment: @Crystal `attributes` is just an object inside your model that contains the properties you define. That way they're kept separate from the Backbone-defined properties.